# Can React Router basename be configured to respect asset URLs in CSS?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, assets, react-router-dom

I am using `BrowserRouter as Router` from `react-router-dom`. I want to host my application at a path that is not `/`. I used the `basename` attribute on the router tag, and it works great.

```html
<Router basename={'/my-cool-path'}>
```

I am referring to images in my react components like this:

```html
<img class="number" src="one.svg"/>
```

The HTML reference works great. But in my CSS files, this breaks:

```css
background-image: url(one.svg);
```

I tried this but it breaks for prod builds (dev env works) :

```css
background-image: url(/one.svg);
```

This works, but only for production builds (`react-scripts build`). It breaks during dev (`react-scripts start` command).

```css
background-image: url(/my-cool-path/one.svg);
```

I want to be able to have CSS URL paths that work when I do **BOTH** a production build and during dev (hot reloading with `react-scripts start` command).

Any ideas for a solution? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: not the way you're hoping.

Problem is, React is Javascript, and your CSS is not handled by Javascript.

You could be saved, if you're compiling CSS - from SCSS for example - you could create a file ie. `env-vars.scss`, and have it define a variable like `$basePath`, setting it to `/my-cool-path/`. ( like `$basePath: "/my-cool-path/";`)

Import that file into your main scss file, and have git (or whatever repo you use) ignore the file. Then you can manually recreate that file on the server, setting the `$basePath` to `/` ( `$basePath: "/";` ).

You can then use the $basePath in your urls in scss, say for example `background-image: url($basePath + "img/some-background.png");`

When ever the scss is compiled, it'll pull the var from that file, and if your repo is ignoring it, you can create different values depending on the environment you're running the compile on.

However building with `react-scripts start` and `react-scripts build` might also provide you a way to set an ENV variable and import it into your scss, but I'm not entirely familiar with this so I'd have to direct you to google for that one I'm afraid.

If you're not compiling your CSS from a preprocessor, it'll be a tougher task.

Comment: I understand, sounds like a valid workaround! I turned my css file into a scss file and added the npm package. According to my debugger network tab, the asset URLs are correct! However, the `react scripts start` is serving the app from `/my-cool-path/` and it is serving the app assets from `/` so all the images are broken in dev, but working in prod build. Any idea of how to get the dev env to serve assets from `/my-cool-path/`?